# Which file encodings are supported for Python 3 source files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

*Before you go telling me to read [PEP 0263](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), keep reading...*

I can't find any documentation that details **which file encodings are supported for Python 3 source files**.

I've found hundreds (thousands?) of questions, answers, posts, emails, etc. about how to declare - at the top of your source file - the encoding of that source file, but none of them answer my question.  Bear with me and imagine doing (or actually try) the following:

1. Open Notepad (I'm using regular old Notepad on Windows 7, but I doubt it matters; I'm sure your superior editor can do something similar.)
2. Type your favorite line of Python code ( I used `print( 'Hello, world!' )` )
3. Select "File" -> "Save"
4. Select a folder and file name ( I used "E:\Temp\hello.py" )
5. **Change the "Encoding:" setting from the default "ANSI" to "Unicode"**
6. Press "Save"
7. Open a command prompt, change to the folder containing your new file, and try to run it

Here's the output I get:

```
E:\Temp>python --version
Python 3.4.1

E:\Temp>python "hello.py"
  File "hello.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file hello.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Now, when I open this same file in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and look at the "Encoding" menu, it has the option "Encode in UCS-2 Little Endian" selected.  [Wikipedia tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) that this is basically UTF-16 encoding.  Whatever.  I don't really care.  More research reveals that my editor has inserted a two-byte BOM (Byte Order Mark) with a value of '\xff\xfe' at the front of the file to indicate the file encoding.  So at least I know where the '\xff' code that Python is complaining about comes from.

So I go and read [PEP 0263](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) - and everything else regarding it - on the web, and I try adding a comment like this to the first line of the file

```
# coding: utf-16
```

with all sorts of different values for the encoding, and nothing helps.  **But it can't help, right?  Because Python isn't even getting as far as my encoding declaration; It's choking on the first byte of the source file!**

So what I really want to know is...

1. Why can't the Python 3 interpreter read this file?
2. If "Unicode" or "UCS-2 Little Endian" or "UTF-16" or *whatever* isn't supported, what is???

P.S.  I even found [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17384280/1193893) which seems to be the exact issue I'm having, but it was closed - erroneously in my opinion - as a duplicate.  :(

--- EDIT ---

Someone asked for my "compiled options".  Here's some output.  Maybe it will help?

```
E:\Temp>python
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> print( sysconfig.get_config_vars() )
{'EXT_SUFFIX': '.pyd', 'srcdir': 'C:\\Python34', 'py_version_short': '3.4', 'base': 'C:\\Python34', 'prefix': 'C:\\Python34', 'projectbase': 'C:\\Python34', 'INCLUDEPY': 'C:\\Python34\\Include', 'platbase': 'C:\\Python34', 'py_version_nodot': '34', 'exec_prefix': 'C:\\Python34', 'EXE': '.exe', 'installed_base': 'C:\\Python34', 'SO': '.pyd', 'installed_platbase': 'C:\\Python34', 'VERSION': '34', 'BINLIBDEST': 'C:\\Python34\\Lib', 'LIBDEST': 'C:\\Python34\\Lib', 'userbase': 'C:\\Users\\alonghi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python', 'py_version': '3.4.1', 'abiflags': '', 'BINDIR': 'C:\\Python34'}
>>>
```

Comment: Can you post your entire hello.py file, from top to bottom, including the "shebang" `#!/bin/env python` or whatever.  Also, your compiled options may help: `import sysconfig;
print(sysconfig.get_config_vars())`

Comment: @jedwards The file contains a single line of code, as stated.

Comment: @also, thanks for the "clarification", but it doesn't help much.  That being said, maybe consult [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).    I have no idea whether it's the list you're interested in, but it seems plausable.  Good luck with your question ...

Comment: "But it can't help, right? Because Python isn't even getting as far as my encoding declaration; It's choking on the first byte of the source file!" Yes, because UTF-16 encoding uses bytes that can't be understood using the default encoding (ASCII in Python 2; UTF-8 in Python 3). "Why can't the Python 3 interpreter read this file?" Because it has to be able to read the encoding declaration before it could switch that encoding.

Comment: "If "Unicode" or "UCS-2 Little Endian" or "UTF-16" or whatever isn't supported, what is???" Ones in which the coding declaration would match the **byte** regex described in PEP 263, as described by the text of PEP 263. This falls out automatically from the fact that the PEP was authored wayyyyyy back in 2001, when `str` meant a sequence of bytes that was only pretending to be a string.

Comment: I agree that the PEP isn't explicit about this, and I can't find official documentation for it even in 2023. However, this information belongs at the canonical - and as it happens, I wrote an answer there that covers this sub-topic a little while ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A source encoding must be:

1. An encoding supported by the version of Python in question. (This varies by version and platform, for example you only get `mbcs` on Windows.)
2. Loosely ASCII-compatible, enough that the `# coding:` declaration can be read using `ascii` which is the initial source encoding before any declaration is read. See PEP0263 ‘Concepts’ item 1.

The encoding that Windows misleadingly calls “Unicode”, UTF-16LE, is not ASCII-compatible (and generally is a barrel of problems you should try to avoid using). Python would need special encoding-specific support to detect UTF-16 source files and this feature has been [declined](http://bugs.python.org/issue1503789) for now.

The `# coding:` you should use is almost invariably UTF-8.

Comment: So the answer *was* there in PEP0263 ('Concepts' item 1): "It does not include encodings which use two or more bytes for all characters like e.g. UTF-16."  Thanks for that.  This requirement is not spelled out very clearly anywhere that I have found, a complaint repeated in the bug/issue/feature-request you pointed out ("Cannot write source code in UTF16").  Thanks for that reference, too.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Python3 code is unicode.  When reading bytes from an external source, the interpreter assume UTF-8 encoding unless the first line after an optional #! line says otherwise.  Similarly, Idle writes with utf-8 encoding unless directed otherwise.  So an explicit UTF-8 should not be needed.