# Valid encodings for a Python source file

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to figure out the entire list of possible encodings for a Python source file - that is, encodings that can go in a [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) encoding specification, like `# -*- encoding: foo -*-`.

Is this list the same as the list given in the documentation for the `codecs` library, under ["Standard Encodings"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)? If not, where can I find the actual list?

(I know that list is the same as the set of unique values in CPython's [/Lib/encodings/aliases.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/encodings/aliases.py), or equivalently, the set of filenames in [/Lib/encodings/](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/encodings/), but again I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the valid encodings for a Python source file are precisely those listed in `codecs`, at least in CPython.

CPython's tokenizer evaluates the value `io.open(<FILE>, "r", -1, <ENCODING>, None, None, False).readline` and then uses that function to read lines (source: [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Parser/tokenizer.c#L516-L530) of CPython's `Parser/tokenizer.c`). Thus, whichever encodings supported by `open()` are also supported in the encoding declaration.

See also: [Which file encodings are supported for Python 3 source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26132121/1757964) and its answers